# MYSQL 5.x select case in select

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to do this within a Select query?

```
select case customField4
   case '4'
      customField4 = 'bob'
   case '5'
      customField4 = 'bill'
   case '6'
      customField4 = 'terry'
   case '7'
      customField4 = 'bobby'
   case '8'
      customField4 = 'sue'
```

But within a select query? I've seen If Else but that only gives me 2 options to work with. I need more than that.

Help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT CASE customField4
     WHEN '4' THEN 'has 4'
     WHEN '5' THEN 'has 5'
     WHEN '6' THEN 'has 6'
END AS customField4
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your problem could be achieved by simply writing

```
SELECT 'has ' + customField4 AS customField4
```

But in more general terms, yes:

```
SELECT
    CASE customField4
    WHEN '4' THEN 'has 4'
    WHEN '5' THEN 'has 5'
    WHEN '6' ...
    END
```

**Edit:** First snippet is not an option since the question was edited, of course.

Comment: Yes David that is why i made the edit to better understand what i was looking for, not just append.

Answer (score 0):

The SELECT statement would be:

```
SELECT CASE customField4
   WHEN '4'
      THEN 'has 4'
   WHEN '5'
      THEN 'has 5'
   WHEN '6'
      THEN 'has 6'
   WHEN '7'
      THEN 'has 7'
   WHEN '8'
      THEN 'has 8'
   END
```

The `SELECT` keyword is not part of the `CASE`.